# Difference between importing a function and whole library in a module in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

what is the difference between
`const { get } = require('lodash');`
and `const lodash = require('lodash');`
More specifically, from RAM point of view. Is it more efficient to import just a single method?

Comment: Is this question answered somewhere else?  I am trying to answer this question too.

Comment: this documentation should help. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark.  though i believe this is ALSO library dependent.